# the limit of infinite sums using stolz cesaro theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, cesaro-summable

I need to find the limit as n goes to infinity of

$$
{1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}.
$$

I'm trying to figure out if you can use shtolz theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case Stolz is a bad idea (you don't have a *quotient*), but with the squeeze theorem is esay:
$$
{n+1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}\le
{1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}\le
{n+1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}.
$$

Comment: Not that it makes a difference to the final anwer, but could you also put an $n$ in the very left numerator instead of $n+1$. I fail to see how the inequality still works with that $n+1$ Could you please explain?

Comment: do you need it to be with an (n+1) on both sides?

Comment: In ${1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$, the greatest term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$, and since there are $n+1$ terms,  ${1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} \leq \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$. On the other hand, the smallest term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$, so $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} \leq {1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$. Now take limits in the right and left hand side of the inequality, and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: There are n+1 terms instead of n, I missed that. Thanks